# How can I run a python script without using a python editor that includes the smartsheet sdk

Tags: python, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-1.1, smartsheet-api-2.0

One solution I have been trying to convert python scripts into .exe files using things like py2exe and cx_Freeze, but I keep getting errors after running the cmd. Is there any other solutions you guys can think of, or should I just keep trying what I am currently working on.

Notes: I am running Spyder 3.3.1 on anaconda, and using the anaconda prompt to install files and use files I install

Example 1: I compile the program using

```
pyinstaller myscript.py
```

When it finishes running, I am left with a full build folder, but an empty dist folder.

The final Error I get before the cmd prompt stops is:

```
for real_module_name, six_module_name in real_to_six_module_name.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: What are the steps you've taken? What are the errors? Please provide details.

Comment: I will add examples to the question

Comment: This may be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613300 in which someone else encounters the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up using was an addon for python called xlwings. It was a simple install using,

```
conda install xlwings
```

and I just used an excel spreadsheet for input (folder/sheet ids and titles).

I made a macro that allows me to push a single button that launches the code (without having to have a python interpreter open) and it works perfectly.

Thanks to everyone for their constant help and support, I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking to do is run the script without using an IDE, just [run it from the command line](https://www.pythoncentral.io/execute-python-script-file-shell/).

`C:\Python27\python.exe C:\script\path\my_python_script.py`

If you want a double clickable icon, you could wrap this in a batch file.