# Pyinstaller not compiling imported modules with sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pyinstaller

I have a simple Python script, which is pasted below:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn import metrics

def get_average(arr):
    return sum(arr) / len(arr)

def get_median(arr):
    arr = sorted(arr)
    listlength = len(arr) 
    num = listlength//2
    if listlength%2==0:
        middlenum = (arr[num]+arr[num-1])/2
    else:
        middlenum = arr[num]
    return middlenum



iris = load_iris()
sklearn.utils.Bunch

# Data
X = iris.data
# Classes
y= iris.target
# Split data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split (X,y,test_size = 0.2, random_state = 4)


scores = []
best_k = 0
best_score = 0
for k in range (1,30):
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = k)
    knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
    score = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    if score > best_score:
        best_k = k
    scores.append(score)
    # print(scores)

print("Your scores were: ", scores)
print("The best k value was: ", k)
print("The average score was: ", get_average(scores) * 100)
print("The median score was: ", get_median(scores) * 100)
```

I am trying to compile that to an `.exe` file for my boss, who does not have Python, and run it on his machine. I have only ever compiled C and C++ code before using `gcc`, and Java using `javac`.

I tried using the `pyinstaller` module to compile the `.exe`. However, I get the following error when I go to run the `.exe`

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "knn_example_iris.py", line
> 38, in <module>
>     from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier   File "c:\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
> line 627, in exec_module
>     exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)   File "site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>  
> File "sklearn\neighbors\dist_metrics.pxd", line 48, in init
> sklearn.neighbors.ball_tree   File
> "sklearn\neighbors\dist_metrics.pyx", line 52, in init
> sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics ImportError: No module named 'typedefs'
> [12564] Failed to execute script knn_example_iris
```

I have tried the following steps:

- Upgrading pip (`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`)
- Upgrading setuptools (`python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools`) per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613300/pyinstaller-compile-to-exe)
- Recompiling
- Deleting `dist` and trying again

I did make another example file,

`print("hello world").py`

which compiled and runs fine.

I have also tried recompiling the file and found many `WARNING` messages in the compiler I missed the first time.

```
> temporary directory at C:\Users\J39304\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpoxunow1d
> "C:/Users/jerry/Desktop/knn_example_iris.py" 54322 INFO: PyInstaller:
> 3.4 54322 INFO: Python: 3.5.0 54324 INFO: Platform: Windows-10.0.16299 54331 INFO: wrote
> C:\Users\jerry\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpoxunow1d\knn_example_iris.spec
> 54336 INFO: UPX is not available. 54355 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH
> with paths ['C:\\Users\\J39304\\Desktop', 
> 'C:\\Users\\jerry\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpoxunow1d'] 54355 INFO:
> checking Analysis 54356 INFO: Building Analysis because
> Analysis-00.toc is non existent 54356 INFO: Initializing module
> dependency graph... 54359 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
> 54362 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ... 58531 INFO: running
> Analysis Analysis-00.toc 58760 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\python.exe 58976 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python35-32\python.exe
> 59161 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
> dependency of c:\python35-32\python.exe 59347 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\python.exe 59554 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\python.exe 59745 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\VCRUNTIME140.dll 59941 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\VCRUNTIME140.dll 60129 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\VCRUNTIME140.dll 60316 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\VCRUNTIME140.dll 60499 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\VCRUNTIME140.dll 60702 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\python35.dll 60883 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\python35.dll 61074 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\python35.dll 61255 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\python35.dll 61436 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\python35.dll 61624 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\python35.dll 61804 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\python35.dll 61986 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\python35.dll 62185 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\python35.dll 62369 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\python35.dll 62547 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\python35.dll 62734 WARNING: lib not found:
> api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of
> c:\python35-32\python35.dll 62741 INFO: Caching module hooks... 62748
> INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\J39304\Desktop\knn_example_iris.py 63449
> INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils 65132 INFO:
> Processing pre-find module path hook   site 65133 INFO: site:
> retargeting to fake-dir
> 'c:\\python35-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules' 67350
> INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook  
> setuptools.extern.six.moves 78457 INFO: Loading module hooks... 78457
> INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually pyinstaller doesn't support the import of sklearn, see [Pyinstaller Supported Packages](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages), after multiple research, the appropriate answer seems to be a `hook`, but I did not spend enough time on it to explain it properly.

Instead, what worked for me, import manually the lib/methods needed, it should looks like this :

**EDIT**

Add this to the import list:

```
import sklearn.neighbors.typedefs
```

Run `pyinstaller yourfile.py`

Wait until it finishes even if there are warning and error messages.

Then we need to create two dirs in `\\dist\\test\\sklearn\\datasets`:

- `data` in which you need to copy paste the `iris.csv` you can find in `C:\Users\{your_name}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\data`
- `descr` in which you need to copy paste the `iris.rst` you can find in `C:\Users\{your_name}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\descr`

Note that this is my version of python (Python37-32)

Hope it helped

Comment: When I try to do so manually, I get errors like `ImportError: No module named sklearn.datasets.load_iris` Am I formatting this wrong?

Comment: @JerrYM. do you have the problem with any lib you're trying to import ?

Comment: no, if I just run the script (`python knn_example_iris.py`) it runs great!

Comment: Are you working in a venv ? Because if I'm not wrong pyinstaller doesn't use it

Comment: no I don't think so. Simply downloaded python and started writing code, no `venv` set up. I did just rerunning pyinstaller and saw some new messages ,which I am posting now...

Comment: I had a lot too, but that still worked. So to make it clear your first problem was that you had `sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics ImportError: No module named 'typedefs'` while running `pyinstaller yourfile.py` ? And now you can't import other modules ?

Comment: When I tried to run the `.exe` file, I received the `ImportError: No module named typedefs error. I can import other modules just fine. The file even "compiles" in `pyinstaller`, but it is the same result (`ImportError: No module named `typedefs`) when I go to run the `.exe`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195348/discussion-between-nqsir-and-jerry-m).